# Uninitialized Object vs Object Initialized to NULL

Tags: java, null, initialization

I'm working in Java.

I commonly setup some objects as such:

```
public class Foo {
    private SomeObject someName;

    // do stuff

    public void someMethod() {
        if (this.someName != null) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The question is: Is `someName` in this example equated to `null`, as-in I can `reliably for all objects` assume null-checking uninitialized objects will be accurate?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Correct, both static and instance members of reference type not explicitly initialized are set to `null` by Java. The same rule applies to array members.

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf), section 4.12.5:

> **Initial Values of Variables**
>
> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is used:
>
> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a
>   default value when it is created
>
> [...] For all reference types, the default value is `null`.

Note that the above rule excludes local variables: they must be initialized explicitly, otherwise the program will not compile.

Comment: how does this apply to, for example, `char` ? I can do `char test;` but not `char test = null;`

Comment: @xorinzor You cannot assign `null` to `char` because it is a primitive type. Also you cannot do `char test;` inside a method without assigning `test` later on. You can do `char test='a'` if you want, or leave it as `char test;` in a member declaration to get the default value of `'\0'`.

Answer (score 18):

If an `Object` reference has been declared but not instantiated, its value is `null`.

Comment: Only as an instance field of a class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you elaborate please? I'm trying to learn :)

Comment: @SnakeDoc If you declare an Object in a method body, you'll get a compilation error if you try to use it without first initializing it.

Comment: It's worth being precise here - you never declare an object. You declare a *variable*. They're not the same thing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry to bring up a really old discussion, but do you happen to have a reference as to *why* they decided it should cause a compilation error, rather than just making it initialize to `null` like an instance field?