# "local variable uninitialized" error when testing for nullity

Tags: java, initialization

I think I'm missing something quite rudimentary, but in the following code I get the error 
`The local variable array may not have been initialized` at the line where I test for its nullity:

```
int [] array; 
outerloop:
for(int x = xMin;x <= xMax;x++){
    for(int y = yMin;y <= yMax;y++){
        if(condition(x,y)){
            array = new int[2];
            array[0] = x;
            array[1] = y;
            break outerloop;
        }
    }
}

if(array != null){
    //do something
}
```

Why is this? Shouldn't the test just return false in the case that the variable is uninitialized? I've been away from Java for a little while but I didn't think I'd forgotten that much ....

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I dont know the long answer but the short answer is that you need to declare it as int[] array = null;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though primitives and objects may be automatically initialized (objects to null) it is a good habit to initialize them.

**Note**
Local variables must be explicitly initialized. Java will not initialize them for you.

Comment: So a global declaration of `int [] array;` would permit a test via `if(array == null)` but not a local declaration?

Comment: I found that this post answers the question, and your response is closest to getting at the core problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699593/uninitialized-object-vs-object-initialized-to-null

Answer (score 6):

If the condition `x <= xMax` is false, your loop will never execute and thus `if(array != null){    //do something }` will be executed, which will be accessing an uninitialized variable.

Just change:

```
int [] array;
```

to

```
int [] array = null;
```