# can't pass custom class through parcelable if it contains HashMap field - why?

Tags: java, android

I've implemented parcelable for my custom class:

```
public class Tag implements Parcelable {
    int id;
    int type;
    int proficiencyLevel;
    HashMap<String, String> translations;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeInt(type);
        dest.writeInt(proficiencyLevel);

        // if this part is uncommented I get a NullPointerException
        /*
        dest.writeInt(translations.size());
        for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : translations.entrySet()) {
            dest.writeString(entry.getKey());
            dest.writeString(entry.getValue());
        }
        */
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Tag> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Tag>() {
        public Tag createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Tag(in);
        }

        public Tag[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Tag[size];
        }
    };

    private Tag(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        type = in.readInt();
        proficiencyLevel = in.readInt();

        // I've put breakpoint here and it seems to work OK, but then I get a NullPointerException
        // deserialize `translations` field
        /*int size = in.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            String key = in.readString();
            String value = in.readString();
            translations.put(key, value);
        }*/
    }
}
```

Now I pass it like this from activity A:

```
Tag[] tagsList = new Gson().fromJson(tags, Tag[].class);
Intent activityTagsSelectorLauncher = new Intent(this, ActivityTagsSelector.class);
activityTagsSelectorLauncher.putParcelableArrayListExtra("tagsList", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(tagsList)));
startActivityForResult(activityTagsSelectorLauncher, SELECT_TAGS_REQUEST);
```

And receive it like so in activity B:

```
ArrayList<Tag> tagsList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("tagsList");
```

It's all working OK if I don't write `HashMap<String, String> translations` field. I get `NullPointerException` when activity B starts. I've put breakpoint inside constructor `private Tag(Parcel in) {` and there it seems that everything works fine so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get [`NPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html), because you don't initialize your translations `Map`:

```
HashMap<String, String> translations
```

*is like*

```
HashMap<String, String> translations = null;
```

Change declaration and initialize the map:

```
HashMap<String, String> translations = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

After you can use it uncommenting the lines

```
dest.writeInt(translations.size());
for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : translations.entrySet()) {
    dest.writeString(entry.getKey());
    dest.writeString(entry.getValue());
}
```

**UPDATE:** to clarify what is happening, **you declare variable and do not initialize it**, so `JVM` does, and translates into `HashMap<String, String> translations = null`.

> **Initial Values of Variables**
>
> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is used:
>
> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created
>
> [...] For **all reference types, the default value is null**.

Take a look at this default initialization table:

```
Type        Default Value
---------   -------------
boolean     false
byte        (byte) 0
short       (short) 0
int         0
long        0L
char        \u0000
float       0.0f
double      0.0d
object      null         <-------------- YAY!
```

After, **when you try to get size with `translations.size()` is same as `null.size()`, there is your [`NPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)**...

Another scenario in a bigger code, is you may not want to initialize `translations`, so you can `safe-check` your sentence by:

```
dest.writeInt(translations != null ? translation.size() : 0);
```

For further info take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html), and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699593/uninitialized-object-vs-object-initialized-to-null)

Comment: Thanks, indeed that was the error. Can you please add a bit more about what happened during parceling and how it led to NullPointerException?

Comment: thanks, but `when you try to get size with translations.size()` - here the translations should not be `null`, since here `Tag[] tagsList = new Gson().fromJson(tags, Tag[].class);` they are populated with values, or they not?

Comment: **You cannot populate a `null` object**, populate does not mean create and fill, it only means fill... You need to populate an empty (or already existing) object...

Comment: Ah, I see, so basically `fromJson` didn't populate `translations` object, but it wasn't obvious until I requested it, correct?

Comment: right! you may need to check if null and then create and populate, or maybe populate ONLY if is empty and not null.... there are plenty of possibilities and JVM only does what you say to *her* ;)

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! I thought that `fromJson` method creates objects and populates them and not just populate existing ones...

Answer (score 0):

null error => due to missing initialization.
Please initialize your hashmap.

Assume that you are passing this parcel ActivityA to ActivityB

I will share full code for those people who are having difficulty passing hashmap

**Parcelable - Tag.java**

```
    public class Tag implements Parcelable {
    int id;
    int type;
    int proficiencyLevel;
    HashMap<String, String> translations = new HashMap<String,String>(); // initialize
...
 @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeInt(type);
        dest.writeInt(proficiencyLevel);

      //add below 
       dest.writeInt(translations.size());
        for (String s: translations.keySet()) {
            dest.writeString(s);
            dest.writeString(records.get(s));
        }

    }

...

private Tag(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        type = in.readInt();
        proficiencyLevel = in.readInt();

        //add below 
        int count = in.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            translations.put(in.readString(), in.readString());
        }

    }
...
   //same as your code
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Tag> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Tag>() {
        public Tag createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Tag(in);
        }

        public Tag[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Tag[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**Activity A**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ActivityA extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ParcelTest p = new ParcelTest();
        p.put("green", "go");
        p.put("yellow", "wait");
        p.put("red", "stop");

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelable("com.example.trafficlight", p);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        i.putExtras(b);

        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**Activity B**

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        ParcelTest p = b.getParcelable("com.example.trafficlight");

        String red = p.get("red");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Credit http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/10/28/writing-parcelable-classes-for-android/