# What's the difference between 'Car myCar = new Car();' and 'Car myCar;'?

Tags: java, class, oop, initialization

Found this second way of initializing an object in a book. Pretty confused right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninitialized Object vs Object Initialized to NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699593/uninitialized-object-vs-object-initialized-to-null)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This declares a variable:

```
Car myCar;
```

That variable is of type `Car` and is called `myCar`.  However, it hasn't been initialized to anything yet.  It's a placeholder for a `Car` object, but no such object has been placed there.  So its *value* is `null`.

This declares *and* initializes an instance:

```
Car myCar = new Car();
```

You can logically think of it as the following two statements in one:

```
Car myCar;
myCar = new Car();
```

A variable is declared and created, set as a placeholder, *and* an instance of `Car` is put there.

---

**Edit:**  More specifically (and I learned something here just now), the value is `null` *if* it's a class-level member.  For example:

```
class MyClass {
    Car myCar;

    void someMethod() {
        // myCar is "null" here
    }
}
```

*However*, if it's a *local* variable in a method, it's slightly different:

```
class MyClass {
    void someMethod() {
        Car myCar;
        // myCar is "uninitialized" here.
    }
}
```

The difference is mostly semantic and you *shouldn't* have to worry about it, unless you have errors or are doing strange things.  The compiler will tell you if you're trying to use an "uninitialized" variable at all, since it can't be used until it's been initialized.  But a `null` variable can be used, it's value is simply `null`.

Comment: If you declare a local variable and don't initialise it, it isn't `null`. It's uninitialised.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement defines a variable and assigns it a value by constructing a new Car instance. The second simply defines a variable without allocating it a value;

Answer (score 1):

`Car myCar;` This doesn't initialize the object, just declare it.

In the statement `Car myCar`; value of myCar is null if `myCar` is an `instance` variable. It is not pointing to any object in memory. You can declare the variable and intialise it before you use it first time otherwise it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

In the statement `Car myCar = new Car();`, there is an object created in memory by name `myCar` of class `Car`.

**declaration:** a declaration states the type of a variable, along with its name. A variable can be declared only once. It is used by the compiler to help programmers avoid mistakes such as assigning string values to integer variables. Before reading or assigning a variable, that variable must have been declared.

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614072/java-define-terms-initialization-declaration-and-assignment)

Comment: `Car myCar;` if this is a local variable, `myCar` isn't `null`; it's uninitialised.

Comment: yes you're right. I'll update difference between instance and local variable